# Can we use google Maps street view in iOS 5 ipad programming With annotations and other features of mapkit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to make  use of google Maps street view in iOS 5 ipad programming With annotations and other features of mapkit

Answer (score 1):

Click on [What's New in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) » iOS 5 » MapKit.

If there is no mention of a new API for that feature, or if the framework is not even listed, then it hasn't been added. This answers all questions about new features in any framework of any iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

You should try apple developer forums as iOS 5 is currently under NDA.

Comment: right! really.. if you post too much about early iOS betas apple might block your account! (they don't want bad infos about iOS bugs to be found on google)

Answer (score 0):

It's available in Maps, but wether it's accessible as an API which I think you're asking, I don't know, expect an answer from someone who has downloaded the beta SDK.
Good luck !